# Drop multiple tables in the same DB -starts with same prefix - Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I drop multiple tables in the same database that starts with same prefix?

Ex:

Query to delete 1 table

```
drop table project_id.db.test_table_<some_random_string>
```

But how can I drop all tables that start with the same prefix `test_table_` in the same db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible work around would be. (region is set eu)

```
BEGIN
DECLARE drop_statments ARRAY<string>;
DECLARE len int64 default 1;

SET drop_statments = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG( 'drop table ' || table_schema ||'.' || table_name)
                      FROM `region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
                        WHERE table_schema = 'db' and table_name like 'Table_Prefix%'
                    );


WHILE ARRAY_LENGTH(drop_statments) >= len DO
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  drop_statments[offset(len-1)];
    SET len = len +1;
END WHILE ;

END;
```

You may use any of below INFORMATION_SCHEMA dataset.

```
-- Returns metadata for tables in a single dataset.
SELECT * FROM myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

-- Returns metadata for tables in a region.
SELECT * FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Comment: Thanks @narendra! Replacing region-us with db worked like a magic for me! Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to narendra@ solution, but using [`FOR..IN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#for-in):

```
FOR drop_statement IN 
  (SELECT CONCAT("drop table ",table_schema,".",   table_name, ";" ) AS value
      FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES -- or region.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE table_name LIKE "table_prefix%"
      ORDER BY table_name DESC)
DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(drop_statement.value); -- Here the table is dropped
END FOR;
```

It's also worth to mention, that you can change "table" to "view" also depending on the information returned from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) views.